# CouchDB documents become deleted after resolving conflicts

Tags: nosql, couchdb, couchdb-futon

I have two CouchDB (v3.3.2) instances which run in docker containers, one instance is run locally and one is a remote instance in the cloud. The local will sync with the remote and the remote will sync with the local. So if I update a document in the local instance, the remote instance document will also be updated and vice-versa. I am running a continuous sync.

I am currently in the testing stage, seeing if CouchDB is the right fit for our application. Right now I am testing conflict resolution. I am simultaneously updating the same document on the local and remote instance, causing conflicts. I am using the Fauxton GUI to choose a winner each time a conflict arises. After causing and resolving a conflict for a document four/five times, for some reason the document becomes deleted and I have no idea why this is happening. I have tried this multiple times and the same behaviour occurs. None of my conflicts involve deletion of a document, they are simply updates to one of fields of a document.

So for more context, I loaded 100 dummy producers into the DB, as you can see at the beginning the first page had producers 1-10:

[image: Producers 1-6 are present]

And now in the first page you can see that producers 1-6 have gone:

[image: producers 1-6 are now gone]

During the conflict resolution stage, all I would do for these producers is to select a winner, like this using Producer 5 as an example:

[image]

After resolving the conflict, which was around the 5th conflict I had resolved for Producer 5, the producer was deleted. The document ID for Producer 5 ends in `696d`, and you can see in the delete items list, the document for Producer 5 is there, and `deleted=true` for the document:

[image]

I have no idea how this has happened, but it keeps happening. I started off with 100 producers; now producers 1-6 have been deleted and I have only 94. Conflicts never involves deletion of a document, only updates to the same single field. Yet, somehow after selecting a winner after resolving around 4-5 conflicts, the document itself gets deleted.

Any advice with this would be very much appreciated.